# Css unicode shown blank rectangle

Tags: css, unicode

I wrote this:

```
.Class{
   Content: 'f0e8'
}
```

But it shown me a blank rectangle instead the icon i want
Anybody knows why?

Comment: Please provide your html and css so we can help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try the following:

```css
.Class:before {
  content: '\f0e8';
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="Class">Hello</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only use "content" in ::after and ::before Pseudoelements.
Try:

```
div::before {
  content: '\2193';
}
```